# Query efficiency mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

Which query will be more efficient:

```
for id in user.posts:
    Post.objects.get(id=id)
```

or

```
posts = Post.objects(user=user_id)
```

with the next schema

```
Post(Document):
    user = ObjectIdField()

User(Document):
    posts = ListField(ObjectIdField())
```

if there is indexing for `user` field in the `Post` document, and an average of `20` posts for each `User`. Also curious about other usage pattern scenarios

Comment: the 2nd may go faster due to index use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following block, fires as many database queries as you have post in `user.posts` so it will be slow anyway.

```
for id in user.posts:
    Post.objects.get(id=id)
```

but if you use it like this:

```
Post.objects.get(id__in=user.posts)
```

Then the performance will be similar to using `Post.objects(user=user_id)` because the primary key gets indexed by default

I believe you should also use ReferenceField i.o plain ObjectId. They allow for lazy loading of references

```
class Post(Document):
    user = ReferenceField("User")

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

    @property
    def posts(self):
        return Post.objects(user=self)

john = User(name='John').save()
post = Post(user=john).save()

print(john.posts()) # [<Post: Post object>]
```